# form_for signature for Mongoid::Document subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, form-for

I have a Mongoid document as :

```
class Index
  include Mongoid::Document

end
```

And two subclasses for 'Index' as:

```
class PercentileRankIndex < Index

end 

class SocialStockIndex < Index


end
```

I want to create a form_for say 'PercentileRankIndex', this is my existing code signature:

```
<%= form_for ([@index, @question]) do |f| %>
```

which goes to route :  `'percentile_rank_index_questions_path'` as @index is instance of PercentileRankIndex.

However the correct route which exists is: `'index_questions'`

How should my form_for signature look so as the Index instance is created with the appropriate _type attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used form_tag to get around this situation:

```
<%= form_tag index_questions_path(:index_id => @index.id) do  %>

  <%= label_tag :name, "Name:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name %>

  <%= label_tag :weight, "Weight" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :weight %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Save", :method => :post, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to 'Back',  index_questions_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This might not be the cleanest way, but still works. Would love to see anyone coming up with better ideas as well.